# Is it possible for gpioset version 2.0.2 to exit immediately?

Tags: libgpiod

There is an option -p which is stated to be:

`the minimum time period to hold lines at the requested values`

When I execute with -p, the command hangs:

`gpioset -p 0 My-led=1`

The gpio line is set correctly, but the program does not terminate.  If I set the time to 1, the command also does not exit.

Some man pages show this option:

`-m, --mode=[exit|wait|time|signal] (defaults to 'exit')`

However this option no longer exists.

The only think I could come up with:

`gpioset -z My-led=1;pkill gpioset`

`-z, --daemonize       set values then detach from the controlling terminal`

Comment: IIRC 0 means infinite wait. Second, if it’s about led, use proper description in your DT or ACPI instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: And traditional comment that on should understand the difference between context and context-less environments. `gpioset` is in the latter class, and after existing the line state is **undefined**. I don’t think this tool is what you are looking for.

Comment: So what does -p 1 mean?  Since it does not exit after waiting a minute either?  But you do bring up the point that using the LED driver to control any GPIO may be more sensible than using the new libgpiod library which seems to assume some kind of mult-user environment where we need to keep the process up indefinitely when we change the state of a GPIO.

Comment: Actually according to the source code the problem is not in `usleep()` (which actually should not block with 0), but in `poll()` that has `-1` as a timeout. That's what makes the code wait indefinitely. _" The timeout argument specifies the number of milliseconds that  poll() should block waiting for a file descriptor to become ready.  The call will block until either:
•  a file descriptor becomes ready;
•  the call is interrupted by a signal handler; or
•  the timeout expires."_ Last one is not the case, and two others seems not happening in your case. What kind of the libc is in use?

Comment: libc6_2.35-r0.1_cortexa7t2hf-neon.ipk

https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/glibc?h=kirkstone&id=0eb8e67aa6833df0cde29833568a70e65c21d7e5

Version 2.35 it appears.

Note that I have used a newer version of libgpiod to get new features than what comes with this version of openembedded.

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried to ask this in the linux-gpio@ mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try

```
gpioset -t0 My-led=1
```

to get the immediate exit behavior of v1.

The `-p` option is useful in combination with the `-t` to ensure the line is held for at least that long before toggling/exiting, and with the `--interactive` mode to ensure commands cannot toggle lines faster than a given rate.

The `-t` option can also be used to drive a sequence out a line, then exit if 0 terminated else repeat.  e.g. `-t3,1` will blink a line with a 75% duty cycle indefinitely, while `-t3,1,0` will exit after one cycle.

Comment: Re the `-p` option's utility with `-t`: It would be nice if that were mentioned in `man gpioset`   :)

Comment: The line has to be drawn somewhere.  The -p option is documented and works with all other options - nothing says otherwise.  Whenever you set the level of a line the -p option ensures it is held at least that long, independent of the trigger.  It also applies to gpioget, where it determines how long you let the configuration settle before taking the reading, e.g. when applying bias.

Comment: Ah - "works with other options"... I didn't get that.